# Subtract Signed integer from Unsigned integer

Tags: c++, c

```
unsigned int value = 1860;
int data = 1300;
if( (data - value) > 0)
{
    printf("Why it is printing this");
}
```

output : Why it is printing this

I am not understanding why subtraction of signed form unsigned pass through the "if" even though value of variable "data" is less than variable "value". I am really curious how signed and unsigned subtraction 'a small mistake' but leads to a big one because I was using "Delay" function instead of "printf" and my task was getting delayed which was creating chaos.

```
unsigned int value = 1860;
int data = 1300;
if( (data - value) > 0)
{
    Delay(data - value);
}
```

This part is keep on delaying and my task never ends.That means value of "data - value" is negative that's why it goes on infinite waiting. Simultaneously it is passing through the "if" where , the condition is "data-value" > 0 . My Doubt if signed gets converted in unsigned and passes through "if" , then why it is giving negative value to "Delay" function.

Answer (score 18):

`int` data type is by default `signed` in C/C++ i.e. supports negative numbers. When an expression contains both `signed` and `unsigned` `int` values, the `signed int` will be  automatically converted to `unsigned int` and so the result will not be less than `0`.
What you may want to do is this:

```
unsigned int value = 1860;
int data = 1300;
if( (signed)(data - value) > 0)
{
    printf("It should print this!");
}
```

It explicitly converts the result of expression to a `signed` value so that it may be a negative number.